# How to generate and manage API Keys in ASP .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, api-key

I'm building an API Server with ASP .NET Core.
I needed to generate and manage API Keys.
So i searched about that, and i found 'Azure Key Vaults'.
I thought it might be a solution, but it was paid service.
So i wondered what is general way to generate and manage API Keys in ASP .NET Core.
I will be thankful if you help me.

Comment: Check out this tutorial for creating ApiKey Authentication https://youtu.be/Zo3T_See7iI

Comment: Azure Key Vault is used to *store* API keys and other credentials, not generate them. What are you trying to do? Securely storing credentials is *completely* different from generating and managing API keys for clients/customers of your service.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think i wrote a little bit confusing words. I'm sorry about that. I know the usage of Azure Key Vault too. I meant "managing" == "generating" + "storing" + etc. So i wanted to know how to generate api keys and how to store api keys.

Comment: @hangooksaram, do you mean you have an API for which you want to generate keys for its users? If yes, please refer to [Simple and secure custom API Keys using ASP.NET Core](https://www.camiloterevinto.com/post/simple-and-secure-api-keys-using-asp-net-core). Regarding storing the keys, I have informed some options in my answer. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Yes, I checked you answer and i checked the reference in your comment too. Your answer was very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your logic and how you would like the API key to generate if you are doing it by yourself.

You could refer to [Simple and secure custom API Keys using ASP.NET Core](https://www.camiloterevinto.com/post/simple-and-secure-api-keys-using-asp-net-core) to generate API keys.

If you are consuming the APIs in your project then those APIs will provide you with the keys.

Further, It looks like you are concerned about storing/managing the API keys.

In the Development environment, you could try to store it in the `AppSettings.json`, or you could store it using the **Environment variables** or you could try to use **Secret Manager**.

It is quite risky and not recommended to rely on these methods to store the API keys for the production environment. For the production environment, I would suggest you store the API keys in the **Azure Key Vault**. I understand that you need to pay to use it but it is the recommended approach to securely store the API keys.

References:

1. [How to store app secrets for your ASP .NET Core project](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/how-to-store-app-secrets-for-your-asp-net-core-project/ba-p/1527531)
2. [Safe storage of app secrets in development in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows)

Answer (score 1):

Azure Key Vault is great but it has some drawbacks. It costs, isn't that fast and it can become a burden with lots of Keys. There's an AZ303 question about making multiple key vaults to scale.

You know the AppConfig has a FREE tier and you can store your API keys in there:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-configuration/

For Database Connection Strings I'd still use Azure Key Vault, for API keys I wouldn't worry about storing in Azure App Config if there's only a few dozen and its not for externally used services.

Comment: I didn't know AppConfig can store API Keys for free. I will consider that too. Thank you!